# Autoload success/failure when calling class_exists

Tags: php, class, autoload

Is there anyway to know if the autoloader succeeded when calling class_exists?

Comment: 1. don't pass the 2nd argument or pass `false` 2. then check what `class_exists` returned. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check `class_exists` twice.

1. To autoload if necessary
2. To see if class now exists after autoload

My working code is:

```
$autoload = spl_autoload_functions() ? true : false; // spl_autoload_functions can return array, empty array or false, but we need boolean
$should_include = $autoload ? class_exists($className, true) : true;

if($should_include && !class_exists($className, false)){ // make sure the class does not exist before including
    if(is_readable($fileName)){
        include_once($fileName);
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Could not include ' . $className);
    }
}
```

This attempts to use previously-defined autoloaders before falling back.

Answer (score 0):

Just at the end of the autoloader check for class existence.

```
function __autoload($className) {

    //Your code here

    if(class_exists('You_Class', false)) {
        //succeed
    } else {
        //failure
    }
}
```

Comment: If `class_exists` the autoloader won't be invoked. So your code is highly redundant.

Comment: @php-dev so I have to run `class_exists` twice? once to autoload (if there is an autoloader) and once to check that the autoloader succeeded?

Comment: @thisispiers, sorry, no need then for the second call
Just check for return-value of `class_exists`

Comment: @php-dev so `class_exists` sees if the autoload succeeded then checks if the class exists? i've not seen this behaviour documented.

Comment: class_exists, depending on the second argument which is by default set to true, checks if the class exists and if it does not exist then try to autoload it. You should consider the autoloader failed if the class didn't exist when calling the `class_exists` with second argument = `true` or ommited